# Is using Transactions a good idea for smartcard writing?

Tags: c#, transactions, smartcard

We are using a custom smartcard to which we read and write data through a COM (over USB) interface.

Whenever we add or update a record, there needs to be some administration done on the card to ensure that other info (mainly pointers) is updated. The info on the card is basically a 64k byte array. On a single add or update, data is read and written at various points in the byte array.

I would like to enforce a way to do the entire update atomically as it were. If we are in the middle of a write and the smartcard is pulled out, the data can easily become corrupt, especially because in essence it's just one continuous byte array, one byte out of place can mess up the validity of the entire array. I would like to make the chance of this happening as small as possible.

I have looked into `TransactionScope`, but this mainly seems to be used for database transactions. Is a mechanism like this useful for my problem or should I be looking at other ways to enforce my software block to read and write in a valid manner?

The smartcard we use is provided to us by a government institution and therefore not subject to change. It has a memory chip, the same you see on your SIM-card for your telephone and a lot of bank cards have it as well (as opposed to the magnetic strip).
The card is designed using the ISO-7816-15 specs. The interface to and from the card has originally been designed by another programmer and he basically said to me: I only deal with bytes going in and bytes going out, I don't do any validation. This seemed weird to me, because I would assume it's his duty to not let the card become corrupted so easily. Apparently it's mine.

I will look into the more technical specs although that's leading me way out of my comfort zone and I don't want to mess with his code unless I absolutely need to. Maybe the card has some better methods to use than what's currently been done.

There is a simple READ-command which only supports reading 231 sequential bytes at once. When I asked him why this is and why I couldn't get the entire byte-array in one go he said that's all the card supported. So reading the entire file is really awkward. It gets worse because once it's "full" it's supposed to leap around to the beginning of the array. :S

Comment: write a transactional file system (2 phase commit) (if the devices SDK doesn't already have one)...

Comment: Why the -4? I've tried to explain as good as I could what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've indicated that you are using a file based smart card, as ISO 7816-15 defines a "directory structure" for finding files and objects such as keys on the card. Smart cards are processor cards that can be programmed in some way or other (until they are fused, and only if you have access to the right keys of course).

File based cards are based on ISO 7816-4, which should be part of your inventory if you want to do anything with smart cards. In there are definitions on what files should look like. Sounds like you are dealing with a card that supports a Cyclic EF, which is a less common Elementary File (EF) structure.

In ISO 7816-4 there are also methods for determining the size of files. Normally this information is returned using the FCI (file control information) information returned from a correctly formatted SELECT FILE by FID APDU instruction. To read all the data as a transaction, just read out all the information and return an exception of some kind if an ISO 7816-4 status word is returned that indicates and error, or if a transmission error occurs.

Now writing data is a bit more problematic as you will need support from the smart card to accomplish such a thing. Many cards do support this kind of functionality, mostly indicated as "card tear" support, as all power is dropped from the processor once the card is suddenly removed from the reader (!).

You can combine both of the above (aggregate APDU calls) within one method to create a transaction. It should be easy to buffer all data in memory anyway, we're not talking about gigabytes of data here.

Comment: In your case, you may have noticed that your knowledge about smart cards is not really adequate to be able to handle them, or even communicate meaningfully with your colleague. I would very much advice you to buy some books about the subject.

Comment: Well, would love to read some books, but time pressure is an issue here. A lot of the software has been made by an "expert", but he only deals with bytes on the way in and bytes on the way out, doesn't even do validation of any kind so that's all up to me. I was just hoping to understand his part better, because he's no longer working on the project.

Comment: Well, that's OK, as long as you indicate somehow to the company that they are not really performing in a professional matter. Transaction support must be understood/documented somewhere before you proceed. Maybe they can get in contact with the previous developer in this case. But that is not directly your problem I suppose.

Comment: We did get in contact with the previous developer, it wasn't very helpful. Luckily, it isn't indeed directly my problem and there are many other problems besides this one. I'm just a simple programmer doing my job the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real smart card (as opposed to a memory card, but I can't derive that from "custom smartcard"), addressing its memory as a byte array is a *very* unusual work split between the host application (everything) and the smart card application (nearly nothing).
It also makes things for the smart card more difficult, since checksums for files are a standard mechanism but if you have to integrate a 64kByte array in a checksum, this may take noticable time. A transaction spanning multiple statements is unusual, but possible (compare ISO 7816 part 7, where it is also in the neighborhood of card SQL, aka CSQL); whether your card supports it for non CSQL sequences has to be looked up in the documentation.

My recommendations would be:

- try to use more card functionality to cover distinct but connected information as far as possible in a single card command. (This also helps for fine-granular access conditions when needed).
- check the manual and possible use a card from another manufacturer supporting multiple statement transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will incorporate my answers into my original question.